# Tumblr theme sidebar and infinite scroll?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I have a question regarding a simple tumblr theme I'm trying to make.

I've never really done a theme before and can't find specific information on what I'm trying to do.

1. I need to get the sidebar links to be links that you can hover over, and also be able to space the "About" from the main text without having to put white text beneath.
2. I also need to space the bottom of the posts with the bottom of the page more, because as you can see there's space at the top but not the bottom...
3. The last thing is that I need to get infinite scroll on my page so there's no need to change pages.
4. How do I get the sidebar and every post to be slightly bordered, the same color as the lines on the background?

I know that these are very simple questions, but I'm new to this and confused. Thanks so much!

The website name is jake-bellissimo.tumblr.com

And the code is:

http://pastebin.com/FeHSKSdu

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I confess I've never made a tumblr theme, but it looks like it's some basic CSS that you need.

1. [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo selector and padding ([box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model))
2. Again, look at padding/margin ([box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model))
3. Infinite scroll implementation will require some custom javascript and server side code. Not sure if tumblr supports this.
4. Borders are also achieved with the css border property [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

You'll probably need to read up on CSS before you try making a theme for tumblr. Again, I'd recommend the articles on [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)